# How to access current $scope from service $rootScope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have created service that creates popup dialog and pass $scope to that service to compile html with $compile provider.
I want to not pass $scope to the service and simple compile html for current $scope.
I try to access current scope from $rootScope via $$childTail property but my $scope's data is not presented in compiled html.

```
...
$compile(popupContents)($rootScope.$$childTail);
```

Is there way to implement that functionality as described above?